# How to get \trianglelefteq similar to \leqslant?

Tags: symbols, relation-symbols

I find `\leqslant` command producing nicer output then `\leq`. For the ideal/normal subgroup symbol, however, one has `\trianglelefteq` (or `\unlhd`), but no slant version.

The `mathabx` package changes the `\trianglelefteq` itself, but also makes the triangle narrow, which doesn't make me happy.

Is there any other solution to this?

Comment: not a help, but to record the fact -- this variation wasn't among the symbols requested for the stix project, so it isn't recognized by unicode or in the stix fonts.  if you can provide a pointer to its use in a published document, i'll be happy to submit it for consideration.  presumably there is also a right-pointing version, and negated forms of both?  my hunch is that, if unicode accepts it, it will ba as a "recognized variant", encoded as the base symbol followed by the math "variant selector", U+FE00.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I stack a `\rule` atop the `\leqslant` in order to make `\trianglelefteqslant`, without the `mathabx` package.  By using the `scalerel` package's features, it can be made to work across math styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\stackMath
\def\trianglelefteqslant{\ThisStyle{\mathrel{%
  \stackinset{r}{.75pt+.15\LMpt}{t}{.1\LMpt}{\rule{.3pt}{1.1\LMex+.2ex}}{\SavedStyle\leqslant}%
}}}
%\usepackage{mathabx}
\begin{document}
$x \leqslant y$\par
$x \trianglelefteqslant y$\par
$\scriptstyle x \trianglelefteqslant y$\par
$\scriptscriptstyle x \trianglelefteqslant y$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not so sure this is better looking (but I dislike `\leqslant` as well).

Probably you'll think to a better name than `\slunlhd`. `;-)`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\slunlhd}{%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\sl@unlhd\relax}%
}

\newcommand{\sl@unlhd}[2]{%
  \sbox\z@{$#1\lhd$}%
  \sbox\tw@{$#1\leqslant$}%
  \dimen@=\ht\tw@
  \advance\dimen@-\ht\z@
  \ifx#1\displaystyle
    \advance\dimen@ .2pt
  \else
    \ifx#1\textstyle
      \advance\dimen@ .2pt
    \fi
  \fi
  \ooalign{\raisebox{\dimen@}{$\m@th#1\lhd$}\cr$\m@th#1\leqslant$\cr}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$N\slunlhd G_{\slunlhd}$

\Large
$N\slunlhd G_{\slunlhd}$

\end{document}
```

Basically, I superimpose `\leqslant` to `\lhd` (with a small correction in text and display styles).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I find a method from `symbol-a4`, page16. It needs `stmaryrd` Package, and the command is `\trianglelefteqslant` and `\trianglerighteqslant`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\begin{document}
$x \trianglelefteqslant y$
\end{document}
```